# #each over an array does not output correctly in handlebar

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a helper method that takes one of my hashes and creates an array out of the keys:

**signup-services-array.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {
  var serviceSignups = [];
  var hash = params[0];
  Object.keys(hash).forEach(function(key) {
    serviceSignups.push(key);
  });

  return serviceSignups;
});
```

In my handlebar view, if I call `{{signup-services-array model.signedServices}}`, I see the output `caviar,doordash,lyft`.

However, if I try to iterate over it, I don't see anything:

```
<ul>
  {{#each signup-services-array model.signedServices as |service|}}
    <li>{{service}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**How do I loop over the array in handlebar?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your helper in `()`:

```
<ul>
  {{#each (signup-services-array model.signedServices) as |service|}}
    <li>{{service}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: nice. this works. thanks. will accept answer when it lets me